# Execute php (wordpress calls) which generates html after page load

Tags: php, html, wordpress, onload

I have a wordpress blog in a sub-directory on my site and display a few of the lastest posts on my homepage. To do that a use the following code

```
<?php
// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');
?>
<?php
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=4'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

I've been trying to figure out if its possible execute this code after the page has loaded, because this is slowing down my page.
I've tried using the body onLoad function, which does execute the code correctly but the generated html doesn't display

```
<body onLoad="init();">

<script language="javascript">
function init()
{
ABOVE CODE IN HERE
}
</script>
</body>
```

Can anyone tell me what to do

Comment: Really, you put php code in a script tag and it executed correctly?

Comment: Anyway you can do this with AJAX, but how is a fairly large topic.

Comment: I don't really know which direction to head in, looking for some tips to point me the right way

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is through AJAX.

Create a page sidebar_render.php. Put that php code in a file, say sidebar_render.php.
Insert into your page these tags to include jquery and then to fetch the HTML and put it somewhere.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: '/sidebar_render.php',
         data: {},
         success: function(data){
              $('#your_wp_sidebar').html(data);
              },
         dataType: 'html'
       });
</script>
```

This will retrieve sidebar_render.php HTML, and then make it appear in the tag with the id you specify. So, you need to fill in the proper location in the 'success' function.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/